# Rails3: not render view if no record found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here's my controller method

```
def check    
 @added_word = Word.where(:word => params[:word][:word]).first

 respond_to do |format|  
  format.js     
 end
end
```

In the view I have the following code:

```
    $("#added_words").append("<%= @added_word.word %>, ");
```

How should i change the controller in order not to render the view if no record found ( false returned)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very idiomatic, but it answers your question.

```
def check    
  @added_word = Word.where(:word => params[:word][:word]).first
  if @added_word.present?
    respond_to {|f| f.js}
  else
    render :text => '' # or whatever
  end
end
```

Comment: You could also do: `render :nothing => true`